# How to re-render only the JSX in function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I'm learning react by making a battleship game. My grid looks like this:

```
const [board, setBoard] = 
   useState([{ship: false, beenHit: false}, {ship: true, beenHit: false},
               {ship: true, beenHit: false},{ship: false, beenHit: false},
               {ship: false, beenHit: false},{ship: true, beenHit: false}
              ])
```

Each field is an object, with 2 properties, implying wether the field has a ship on it, and if the player has already clicked on it. I assigned receiveHit() function to each field, so when the player clicks on the field, it marks the object in the array as {ship: true, beenHit: true}. It works fine, but the problem is, the grid doesn't re-render itself, so the color of the field won't change.

The function for deciding the className (and thus the color of the field):

```
function decideColor(field){
     if(field.beenHit && field.ship){
        return 'red'
     } else{
         return 'blue'
       }
}
```

The retruned JSX:

```
return ({
 board.map((field, i)=> <div onClick = {() => board.receiveHit(i)} className = {decideColor(field)}> 
 </div> )
})
```

It's inside a functional component. I cant re-render the whole component, as the position of the ships will change (they are placed on the board randomly)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are setting the field directly in the state. This way the board object stays the same, and won't trigger a re-render. You have to re-assign the state and thus create a state-change for react to react upon. The thing is: you are not re-rendering the whole component. Your function is returning the new state, yes. But React's internal mechanism decides what needs to be re-rendered to the DOM and what not (props and keys play a role in here, make sure to use them). Take my example, open the DevTools and watch the changes that are made when you click on a box. You will see only the clicked-upon div was rendered to the DOM. It is therefore wise to make a lot of smaller components to make the re-renders more efficient.

```css
.board {
  display:flex; 
  width: calc(20em + 20px); /* 10 x 10 field with borders */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.field { 
  display:inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.field.ship {
  background-color: blue;
}

.field.hit {
  background-color: grey;
}

.field.ship.hit {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```js
const Field = ({field, ...props}) => {
  return <div {...props}/>
}

const Board = () => {
  // init 10 x 10 board
  const [board, setBoard] = React.useState([...new Array(100)].map((elem, index) => {return {}}));
  const onClick = (event, i) => {
    // This takes the existing board, replaces the element with the index i 
    // with hit set to true. And sets the newly created *copy* as the new 
    // version of the board. It will trigger a re-render but as mentioned
    // before, only the truly changed (in this case className changes) will 
    // rendered to the DOM.
    setBoard(Object.assign([...board], {
        [i]: {
            ...board[i],
            hit: true
        }
    }));
  }  
  
  const decideClassName = (i) => {
    // color is based on the keys and the resulting class combination,
    // field, field ship, field ship hit, and field hit (see CSS)
    return `field ${Object.keys(board[i]).join(" ")}`;
  }
  
  const setShip = (board, x, y, length, type = "horizontal") => {
    const index = y * 10 + x;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      board[index + i * (type == "horizontal" ? 1 : 10)].ship = true;  
    }
  }
  
  // init ships
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const copy = [...board];
    setShip(copy, 5,5,4);
    setShip(copy, 2,2,3, "vertical");
    setBoard(copy);
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div className="board">
      {
        board.map((field, i) => <Field key={`field-${i}`} field={field} onClick={(event) => onClick(event, i)} className={decideClassName(i)}/>)
      }
    </div>

  )
}
    
ReactDOM.render(
    <Board/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```